Angular scroll directive not firing
I would like to get a console.log() once the scrollbar in the dropdown reaches bottom to implement infinite scrolling / "load more" feature:

On the code below, I created a ScrollEndDirective directive which will just emit to component file:
export class ScrollEndDirective {
  @Output() scrolledToEnd = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log('constructor logger'); // <- this is logging
  }

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: Event): void {
    const element = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    console.log(element); // <-- this is not even logging

    if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight) {
      this.scrolledToEnd.emit(true);
    } else {
      this.scrolledToEnd.emit(false);
    }
  }
}

below is the component file:
@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-auto-complete-options',
  template: `
    <div class="example-input">
      <input
        placeholder="input here"
        nz-input
        [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
        (input)="onInputChange($event)"
        [nzAutocomplete]="auto"
      />
      <nz-autocomplete #auto scrollEnd (scrolledToEnd)="onScrollEnd($event)">
        <nz-auto-option *ngFor="let option of options" [nzValue]="option.name">{{ option.name }}</nz-auto-option>
      </nz-autocomplete>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class NzDemoAutoCompleteOptionsComponent {
  inputValue?: string;
  options: string[] = [];
  private searchSubject = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.searchSubject
      .pipe(
        // debounceTime(1000), // debounce for 1 second
        switchMap((value) => this.search(value))
      )
      .subscribe((options) => {
        this.options = options;
      });
  }

  onInputChange(event: Event): void {
    const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.searchSubject.next(value);
  }

  search(value: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<string[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .pipe(map((response) => response));
  }

  onScrollEnd(atEnd: boolean): void {
    console.log('Scrollbar is at the end');
  }
}


As you can see, directive is added to component nz-autocomplete. It is a ng-zorro Autocomplete component (https://ng.ant.design/components/auto-complete/en).
Can you help me please to understand why it is not functioning correctly? I these guess:

because nz-autocomplete could be not really scrollable
nz-autocomplete internal code does not allow directive?
Wrong scroll directive code. I am new to directives and just copied the code online.

Reason why I decided not to use ng-zorro's Select where infinite loading is directly built-in to it:

I don't like the input to display NotFoundContent when user clicks and empty input field. If no input value, just focus on input and show nothing (how ng-zorro's Autocomplete works). I would like to only display it when there are no actual results.



I want the currently selected/inputted text to retain on the field. In ng-zorro's Select, whenever user selected, you cannot delete previously inputted text. In image below, I want to clear the "apple" text but it does not allow me to as it becomes a placeholder now


I would also appreciate if you can help me tweak ng-zorro's Select to my liking if its easier. Thank you.
Stackblitz link to my repo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awrmdb-4dhtrr

Look at the HTML with the inspector from your browser dev tools.  is empty. This component calculates where the dropdown should be placed and dynamically inserts a container directly to the  element. I guess it does this to avoid issues with z-index and ensure the dropdown always shown on top.

you're right. dropdown options are on "cdk-overlay-container". hmm

As you said, it's better to go for nz-select because there will be the least amount of bugs with this approach and simply simulate the autocomplete.
Please find below the attributes that were used to achieve, serversearch and search box for the nz select. I also used nzFocus to achieve the showing of the selected item on the search box. Feel free to tune it to your liking.
I used the below CSS to hide the placeholder like text:
::ng-deep .ant-select-single.ant-select-open .ant-select-selection-item {
    display: none !important;
}
::ng-deep .ant-empty{
  opacity:0;
  /* display:none */
}

HTML
<nz-select
    #select
    nzShowSearch
    nzServerSearch
    nzPlaceHolder="select something" 
    style="width:100%;"
    nzPlaceHolder=""
    [(ngModel)]="selected"
    (nzOnSearch)="searchSubject.next($event)"
    (nzFocus)="focus()">
    <nz-option
      *ngFor="let option of options"
      [nzLabel]="option.name"
      [nzValue]="option.name"
    ></nz-option>
  </nz-select>

TS
  focus() {
    if (this.selected) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const input = this.select?.nativeElement?.querySelector('input');
        input.value = this.selected;
      });
    }
  }

FULL CODE:
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  Output,
  HostListener,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollEnd]',
})
export class ScrollEndDirective {
  @Output() scrolledToEnd = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log('constructor logger'); // <- this is logging
  }

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: Event): void {
    const element = this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    console.log(element); // <-- this is not even logging

    if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight) {
      this.scrolledToEnd.emit(true);
    } else {
      this.scrolledToEnd.emit(false);
    }
  }
}

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-auto-complete-options',
  template: `
    <div class="example-input">
      <nz-select
        #select
        nzShowSearch
        nzServerSearch
        nzPlaceHolder="select something" 
        style="width:100%;"
        nzPlaceHolder=""
        [(ngModel)]="selected"
        (nzOnSearch)="searchSubject.next($event)"
        (nzFocus)="focus()">
        <nz-option
          *ngFor="let option of options"
          [nzLabel]="option.name"
          [nzValue]="option.name"
        ></nz-option>
      </nz-select>

      {{selected  | json}}
      <!-- <nz-autocomplete #auto scrollEnd (scrolledToEnd)="onScrollEnd($event)">
        <nz-auto-option *ngFor="let option of options" [nzValue]="option.name">{{ option.name }}</nz-auto-option>
      </nz-autocomplete> -->
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    ::ng-deep .ant-select-single.ant-select-open .ant-select-selection-item {
        display: none !important;
    }
  `,
  ],
})
export class NzDemoAutoCompleteOptionsComponent {
  @ViewChild('select', { read: ElementRef }) select!: ElementRef<any>;
  selected = null;
  isOpen = false;
  inputValue?: string;
  options: string[] = [];
  private searchSubject = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.searchSubject
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(250), // debounce for 1 second
        switchMap((value: any) => this.search(value))
      )
      .subscribe((options) => {
        this.options = options;
      });
  }

  focus() {
    if (this.selected) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const input = this.select?.nativeElement?.querySelector('input');
        input.value = this.selected;
      });
    }
  }

  search(value: string) {
    return this.http
      .get<string[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .pipe(
        map((response) =>
          response.filter((item: any) =>
            item.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
          )
        )
      );
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you sir. you are a lifesaver. Is there a way to hide "No Data" during initial click? with no search term at all? or we cannot as that is how ng-zorro behaves?
I tired using [nzNotFoundContent] directive with custom template but it just shows empty div/dropdown below
Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awrmdb-ff1dme

@Welp I updated my answer, I just hid the no data element, you can try the same!

@Welp If you want to do it conditionally, just use ngClass to add a class, which will trigger the CSS to hide, the class will show if selected has a value, we need to add the nz-select the class!
